# How can I minimize a number without if/for

Tags: python

I need help writing a function.
If b is less than one tenth of a, the result is zero. If not, a is produced.
Note that I am a beginner so, if and for are not yet allowed. I can only use math module and min/max.

This is what I have so far:

```
import math

def minimizer(a, b):
  x = (1/10)*a
  
  


minimizer(1000, 3) -> 0
minimizer(1000, 73) -> 0
minimizer(1000, 233) -> 233
minimizer(1000, 1222) -> 1222
```

Comment: In the question you say if - else return a, but in the code you do if - else return b. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

The *more readable* way to "*return 0 if b is less than one tenth of a, otherwise return a*",  would be to simulate a `ternary operator` like this:

```
def minimizer(a,b):
    return 0 if b < (a/10) else a
```

...but if you can't use an `if` statement or a `for` statement you could  *cheat* a little and use a `while` statement...

```
def minimizer(a,b):
    while b < (a / 10):
        return 0
    
    return a
```

... or, a much better solution, would be to use a `tuple` and `indexing`. A `True` condition will evaluate to 1 while a `False` condition to 0:

```
def minimizer(a,b):
    return (a, 0)[b < (a / 10)]
```

Instead of a `tuple` you are free to use a `list`:

```
def minimizer(a,b):
    return [a, 0][b < (a / 10)]
```

This can be further simplified, as suggested by [@SUTerliakov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561355/how-can-i-minimize-a-number-without-if-for/67561452#comment119417415_67561452) in his comment. You can multiplying the `integer evaluation` of the condition directly by `a`:

```
def minimizer(a,b):
    return a * (b >= a/10)
```

If it was my production code my top pick would be the `ternary operator`, the second choice the `integer evaluation`. I'd never use the `while` statement to solve a problem like this.

**Output**:

```
print(minimizer(1000, 3))
print(minimizer(1000, 73))
print(minimizer(1000, 233))
print(minimizer(1000, 1222))

0
0
1000
1000
```

Comment: One more way I can suggest is integer evaluation of boolean like `a * (b >= a/10)`

Comment: Yes, I added it to my answer. To be honest I was experimenting with something like it in my Jupiter but your comment came first than my edit :)